# Getting window handle in Java

Tags: java, jframe, window, native, handle

I have been trying to get the current window pointer for a JFrame using the following code:

```
public class MainClass
{
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JPanel controlPanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setSize(400,400);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);

        try {
            jFrame.setVisible(true);
            final HWND hwnd = new HWND(Native.getComponentPointer(jFrame));
            System.out.println(hwnd);

        } finally {
            jFrame.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

However, the result being outputted is always 'native@0x0'. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: The problem will be in the code Native.java.

Comment: I am importing 'com.sun.jna.Native'. What could the problem be? @SteveSmith

Comment: Sorry, I assumed it was your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using windows or Mac? if Mac there is no way that you can get the pointer since this method only gets the pointer of windows from a windows machine.

Comment: Not sure if it'll help get the handle, but using JNA, you can get the Process ID on Mac too.  `CLibrary.INSTANCE.getpid()`, then using AppleScript, you can interact with it by process ID.  It's a hack, but it works.